# Facing error with SXA scriban template

Tags: sxa, scriban

I am trying to access the `multilist` field from datasource in `scriban` template and getting the following error. The code snippet is given below,

[image]

```
<div class="row-section">
{{
    for contentItem in (sc_follow i_item "Item List")
}}
{{ contentType=(sc_follow  contentItem 'Content Section') }}
<div class="slider ">
<div class="content bar">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
    
<div class="card-types">
       <p class="card-type" card-type="{{contentType.Name}}">{{contentType.Name}}</p>
      
</div>

</div>

  </div>
 </div>

 {{
   end
 }}

</div>
</div></div>
{{
 end
 }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to access the `multilist field` from datasource...

```
{{ for contentItem in (sc_followmany i_item "Item List") }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help....it helped me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Please use below `scriban` code to get data from `multilist field`

```
{{ for i_product in (sc_followmany i_page "Related Products") }}
  <h2>{{ sc_field i_product "Title" }}</h2>
  <b>Content</b>:{{ sc_field i_product "Content" }}
{{ end }
```

For more information ,please use below link and to avoid such errors try add if else conditions and add null check.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-embedded-functions-for-the-scriban-template.html